# How to change indirect lighting cache to somewhere else

Tags: lighting, cache

Is is possible that I can store indirect lighting cache somewhere else besides from my Ram? Blender takes up most of my ram when I use indirect lighting so is there a way to bring it to a folder to be stored temporarily?